# trying to use Directory .EnumerateFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Tags: c#, getfiles, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

So i'm using `Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`. When i try it on the `c:\` drive in windows 7, since windows 7 still had `c:\documents and settings` (for legacy systems like xp), it's a protected folder.  It's only protected because it's not really a folder. It's kind of a dummy folder. So when I run this code:

```
try
{
    string[] folders = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\","*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string item in folders)
    { 
       //blah blah
    }
catch
{
}
```

It always throws an UnauthorizedAccessException. It doesn't let me past that. What I'm trying to do is have it skip over any folder that it doesn't have permission to access, but just continue to search, don't get caught up on the catch block, just continue. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `kind of a dummy folder`?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not missing a semi colon in your call? Probably just a typo

Comment: @alexn I think he meant it is a folder-pointer, a shortcut, I am not sure about the correct term for it. It doesn't have data but it points to another location.

Comment: The technical term for it is reparse point, but it's also known as a junction.

Answer (score 2):

I would try one of the two workarounds in this article (click on workarounds tab near the bottom):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94751/optionally-prevent-directoryinfo-getfiles-from-throwing-unauthorizedaccessexception

Comment: I'd suggest the guitar_man one, the other is quite a mess.

Comment: Linking to a now dead link...